# Google OAuth signin redirecturl AWS

Tags: javascript, java, amazon-ec2, google-oauth

I'm trying to use Google OAuth for an application I deployed on AWS cloud. I have created the OAuth credentials and generated the client id.

I add the Authorized JavaScript origins as localhost, which works fine. However, after I add deploy my application on AWS, it doesn't work. I have also added the Authorized JavaScript origins as http://ec2-xxx-xx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com.

It gives me the below error:
[image]

Can someone help me figure it out?

Comment: Still waiting..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I find that Google OAuth doesn't support redirect to dynamical url

http://ec2-xxx-xx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com

we have to give a static DNS name.